# Why show desktop (with alt tab) in kde renders alternatively two different things?

Tags: kde, application-switcher, kde5, show-desktop

If I use task switcher to show the desktop, I obtain the first time:

[image]

The second time:

[image]

And so on further. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

Solved.

Comment: +2 to your interesting question and correct answer to help offset your lost bounty.  https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1066/why-dont-i-get-my-reputation-back-when-i-answer-the-question-myselfThe good news is you are happy with solution.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is window selector Ubuntu and Windows but in KDE it shows the desktop. In Ubuntu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will minimize all Windows and reveal the desktop (with icons).

The OP's solution is to turn off desktop icons using:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

Now there are no icons on the desktop at all, whether you minimize all Windows or not.

---

[Another option](https://superuser.com/questions/996597/kde-plasma-alt-tab-behavior-options-most-of-them-are-missing) is to install **KDE** add-on; `kwin-addons` in [K]ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install kwin-addons
```

---

From [Arch Linux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=218308) this user writes:

> So in KDE you can change the design of the Alt+Tab application
>   switcher. On my previous installation, I always used one called "Large
>   Icons", which was a Mac OS inspired application switcher that only
>   showed icons. In my installation this switcher is no longer available
>   (Settings -> Window Management -> Task Switcher). I can only select
>   Cover switch, Flip switch, Breeze and Breeze dark. Does anyone know
>   where that nice application switcher went?

The solution (which might be your original problem) could be "Large Icons" as this screen (from the Arch Linux link) shows:

[image: kde-alt-tab]