# Uninstall KDE Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kde

I installed system preferences KDE on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS because I wanted to change how apps are shown when Alt + Tab, (followed this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1022714/1181917)). Restarted my computer and it changed the cursor theme and it's annoying me, is there a way to delete or uninstall safely KDE system preferences and get back to what I had? Thanks

Comment: I'd find it easier to understand what you did if you provided the commands you executed, thus what packages you installed (the fix is usually to just remove or purge them). If you're unsure, your command `history` will help remind you (or you can look in `apt` package logs too). I doubt removing packages is necessary, you just change settings to what you like.   (is this https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/kwin-addons what you installed? or something else? or did you do something else as well?)

Comment: Agree with @guiverc. Alternatively to deinstalling the KDE system, which depends on the packages you installed, you could try `gnome-tweaks` to return the cursor theme to the defaults/desired setting.

Comment: I executed `sudo apt-get install kwin-addons` it took a while to install and then I got an application called; KDE System Preferences

Comment: @Mario if I install `gnome-tweaks` I need to somehow disable KDE? Because I can see there similar options in both applications. Thanks for answering

Comment: @Danny Ah, I just understood that your are using KDE in full. In that case, `gnome-tweaks` will unlikely work. Sorry for a bad guess. Try to `sudo apt-get purge kwin-addons ...` incl. everything related to that, then `sudo apt-get autoremove`, re-login, and see what happens.

Comment: @Mario Prompt just showed me that I'm about to do something potentially harmful, that aprox. 11 GB will be free after that action, and that I should conitnue only if I know what I'm doing, so I didn't continue with `sudo apt-get purge kwin-addons ...`

Comment: Hold on, with the informal `...`, I meant `sudo apt-get purge kwin-addons <further explicitly installed KDE packages>` (`sudo apt-get purge ...` matches a large range of packages because of using regular expressions, see https://serverfault.com/questions/926103/apt-get-install-packages-matching-wildcards, definitely NOT meaningful in your case).

Comment: The packages you explicitly installed need to be identified, see @guiverc's suggestions. `sudo apt-get autoremove` will only then help you with removing further packages that were automatically, but not explicitly, installed and no more needed.